# Jquery webservice foreach loop

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to jquery dropdownlist with this result set of webservice, the `getYears` function is returning list of years 2013,2012,2011.... in L`ist<string>` for but when I bind it with `ddlyears` the values coming up as 1,2,3,4,5,6

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../WebService.asmx/getYears",
        data:"{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (msg) {

        for (var myVar in msg.d) {
            $('#ddlyears').append("<option value='" + myVar.toString() + "'>" + myVar.toString() + "</option>");
        }
    },
    error: function (jqerr) {
        errorCaller(jqerr);
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to tell what `msg` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
success: function (msg) {

    $.each(msg.d, function (k, value) {
        $('#ddlyears').append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");
    });
}
```